# R markdown knitr setting the pdf output version

Tags: r, pdf, latex, r-markdown, knitr

Is there a way to set the pdf version of the output when one knits an rmd to pdf output? The default is version 1.5. But I need it to be version 1.3.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are looking to use LaTeX? According to [this link](https://scivision.co/latex-pdfminorversion-graphics/) you can use:

```
\pdfinclusionerrorlevel=1
\pdfminorversion=3
```

Comment: Hi Daniel,
Thanks. Yes, I eventually tried this by editing the tex.ini file located for me in `TinyTeX\texmf-dist\tex\generic\tex-ini-files` , but setting it at minor version 3 crashed my system to produce it. In the end resorted to manual conversion in software using something like Nuance Power PDF.